# How does this line separation make a different?

Tags: c, memory

I was doing system programming in C on creating a server. There was a bug that caused serious issues that results cannot be returned correctly. **I solved the issue by doing a line separation, but did not understand why this solved the issue.**

**Original code** that caused serious issues:

```
 int Bytes, Size  = cache[index].len;
```

**New code** that solved the issue:

```
 int Bytes  = cache[index].len;
 Size = Bytes;
```

**What is the difference between my original code and new code? Are they not identical?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not identical at all. The first code:

```
int Bytes, Size = cache[index].len;
```

Declares two variables, `Bytes` and `Size`, both of type `int`; `Size` is initialized to the value of `cache[index].len` and `Bytes` is uninitialized (its value is indeterminate).

The second code (I'm inserting `int` in the second line to make it a declaration-with-initializer, since I'm assuming this is what you meant):

```
int Bytes = cache[index].len;
int Size = Bytes;
```

Declares the same two variables of the same type; but here, it is `Bytes` that is initialized to the value of `cache[index].len` and `Bytes` is then copied to `Size`.

Comment: Nit... *"its value is undefined"* -> *"its value is indeterminate"*.

Comment: While the value of `Bytes` is "indeterminate" in the first case, attempting to access that value will result in behavior that is *Undefined*. So the value held by `Bytes` in the first case is just whatever garbage is at that memory location on the stack (the value is indeterminate). The act of accessing the indeterminate value is what results in *Undefined Behavior*. (like I said -- Nit.., but an important distinction -- it is how the C Standard words it)

Comment: Its not artificial, it is how the standard is worded to allow a sane distinction between what is `"defined"` and what is `"indeterminate"`. The value is `Bytes` is not undefined, it is quite well-defined to be whatever is at that memory location on the stack. The value at that defined location is `"indeterminate"` until assigned or initialized. See [C11 Standard - 3.19.2(p1) Indeterminate value](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2p1) and [C11 Standard - 6.2.4(p6) Storage durations of objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p6)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for that, I've updated the answer. I still think building a semantic argument on the difference between the two is dubious at best, but I'm happy to use (and to learn) the terminology from the standard.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't dinging you, I was just trying to be helpful and raise the distinction drawn in the standard. Semantically I agree with you undefined/indeterminate -- what's the big deal? But, since the final arbitrator of what can/can't be done is the Standard, I've learned to appreciate the subtle distinctions. Good luck with your coding.